# Displaying collection of objects with ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I am trying to display collection of objects using `ItemsControl`. This is the simple example I created;

```
<Window x:Class="PhotoWieverWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhotoWieverWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Images" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace PhotoWieverWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml etkileşim mantığı
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3"));
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 4"));
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 5"));
            Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 6"));
        }

        public class ListItem
        {
            public string FullName { get; }
            public ListItem(string fullname)
            {
                FullName = fullname;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting a blank window with no errors. I suppose I made a mistake with binding, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I had to use a RelativeSource set the DataContext to Window's before it would bind properly: <ItemsControl x:Name="Images" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"> Since you are using code behind and have an implicit DataContext this may be needed.

Comment: You should have noticed a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application in debugger, telling you that the DataContext is null. Just add `DataContext = this;` to the MainWindow constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Clemens said you forget to set DataContext for your View. You can easily set it to your code-behind's constructor like this:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; // you need this
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 3"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 4"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 5"));
        Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 6"));
    }
```